# Two-column card layout for desktop and mobile

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b6q7pmkg/
I'm trying to achieve two-column cards where it always stays two column regardless on mobile or desktop.
So something like this:
On desktop:
[image]

On mobile:
[image]

Here's what I have so far.. but not quite there..

```
.cardContainer {
  max-width: 30rem;
}
```

css:

```
.root {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
}

.link {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.imageContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 40%;
}

image {
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.large .title {
    font: 400 1.1875rem/1.263 'Avenir Next W01', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 1.1875rem;
    line-height: 1.263;
    letter-spacing: 0.0125rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.body {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    color: rgb(139, 139, 139);
    display: block;
}
.description {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/ks3Ltx1o/) a model with a basic css.

The important thing to know here is the double flexbox; one flexbox for card (img/paragraph), and one flexbox for all the cards, with a `flex-wrap: wrap;` to make sure they're doing their job right.

I use [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) flexbox cheat sheet to remember exactly how flexbox works :)

Here's a copy of the jsfiddle code :

```css
section{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

article{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/" />
    <p>
      Some text.
    </p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/151/100/" />
    <p>
      Some text.
    </p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/101/" />
    <p>
      Some text.
    </p>
  </article>
</section>
```

edit: I [just made](https://jsfiddle.net/ks3Ltx1o/1/) an edit of the fiddle with grey text and vertically centered paragraphs :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS Grid as well:

Put all of your cards in a `<div class="grid-container">`, add the following lines in your CSS:

```
.grid-container{
 display: grid;
 grid-gap: 20px; /*that's optional, for the space between your cards*/
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 300px);
}
```